# Optimizing subquery with function and dual

Tags: oracle

I'm using an Oracle database, and writing a query that involves a resource-intensive user-defined function on sysdate (the function determines a date that's a number of business days in the future, based on an internal calendar). Using this causes the query to run very slowly. Because this value will be the same for every row in the table (since sysdate doesn't vary), I thought it would be optimal to make a subquery with just this function, giving me something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.some_date, b.next_business_day 
FROM a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT add_bus_days(sysdate,1) as next_business_day FROM dual) b
```

This didn't help. I then found that I only needed this next_business_day field for certain rows, so I changed it to a left join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.some_date, b.next_business_day 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT add_bus_days(sysdate,1) as next_business_day FROM dual) b ON a.some_date >= sysdate
```

This ran much faster! Unfortunately, I then found that I couldn't use that ON condition, and needed to go back to a cross join.

So my question is, is there a way I can force it to just run that subquery a single time, rather than for every row it joins to?

EDIT: Here is the query followed by the explain plan results-

```
with nbd as (select ccijc.add_bus_days(sysdate,1) as next_bus_day from dual)

select a.status_date, b.next_bus_day
from ccijc.episodes a
cross join nbd b
order by 2 desc
```

```
"STATEMENT_ID","PLAN_ID","TIMESTAMP","REMARKS","OPERATION","OPTIONS","OBJECT_NODE","OBJECT_OWNER","OBJECT_NAME","OBJECT_ALIAS","OBJECT_INSTANCE","OBJECT_TYPE","OPTIMIZER","SEARCH_COLUMNS","ID","PARENT_ID","DEPTH","POSITION","COST","CARDINALITY","BYTES","OTHER_TAG","PARTITION_START","PARTITION_STOP","PARTITION_ID","OTHER","OTHER_XML","DISTRIBUTION","CPU_COST","IO_COST","TEMP_SPACE","ACCESS_PREDICATES","FILTER_PREDICATES","PROJECTION","TIME","QBLOCK_NAME"
"",2134,26-APR-23,"","SELECT STATEMENT","","","","","",,"","ALL_ROWS",,0,,0,3409,3409,828767,6630136,"","","",,"","","",913862273,3187,,"","","",1,""
"",2134,26-APR-23,"","SORT","ORDER BY","","","","",,"","",,1,0,1,1,3409,828767,6630136,"","","",,"","<other_xml><info type=""has_user_tab"">yes</info><info type=""db_version"">19.0.0.0</info><info type=""parse_schema""><![CDATA[""CCI_RESEARCH""]]></info><info type=""plan_hash_full"">2549094711</info><info type=""plan_hash"">2575214890</info><info type=""plan_hash_2"">2549094711</info><stats type=""compilation""><stat name=""bg"">0</stat></stats><qb_registry><q o=""18"" h=""y""><n><![CDATA[SEL$F5BB74E1]]></n><p><![CDATA[SEL$1]]></p><i><o><t>VW</t><v><![CDATA[SEL$2]]></v></o></i><f><h><t><![CDATA[A]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$1]]></s></h><h><t><![CDATA[DUAL]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$2]]></s></h></f></q><q o=""2""><n><![CDATA[SEL$1]]></n><f><h><t><![CDATA[A]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$1]]></s></h><h><t><![CDATA[B]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$1]]></s></h></f></q><q o=""2""><n><![CDATA[SEL$2]]></n><f><h><t><![CDATA[DUAL]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$2]]></s></h></f></q><q o=""2""><n><![CDATA[SEL$3]]></n><f><h><t><![CDATA[from$_subquery$_004]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$3]]></s></h></f></q><q o=""18"" f=""y"" h=""y""><n><![CDATA[SEL$117FC0EF]]></n><p><![CDATA[SEL$3]]></p><i><o><t>VW</t><v><![CDATA[SEL$F5BB74E1]]></v></o></i><f><h><t><![CDATA[A]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$1]]></s></h><h><t><![CDATA[DUAL]]></t><s><![CDATA[SEL$2]]></s></h></f></q></qb_registry><outline_data><hint><![CDATA[USE_NL(@""SEL$117FC0EF"" ""A""@""SEL$1"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[LEADING(@""SEL$117FC0EF"" ""DUAL""@""SEL$2"" ""A""@""SEL$1"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[INDEX_FFS(@""SEL$117FC0EF"" ""A""@""SEL$1"" (""EPISODES"".""STATUS_DATE"" ""EPISODES"".""DELETE_STATUS"" ""EPISODES"".""EPISODE_ID"" ""EPISODES"".""CREATE_DATE""))]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OUTLINE(@""SEL$2"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OUTLINE(@""SEL$1"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[MERGE(@""SEL$2"" >""SEL$1"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OUTLINE(@""SEL$F5BB74E1"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OUTLINE(@""SEL$3"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[MERGE(@""SEL$F5BB74E1"" >""SEL$3"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OUTLINE_LEAF(@""SEL$117FC0EF"")]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[ALL_ROWS]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_nlj_hj_adaptive_join' 'false')]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_strans_adaptive_pruning' 'false')]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OPT_PARAM('_px_adaptive_dist_method' 'off')]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[DB_VERSION('19.1.0')]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')]]></hint><hint><![CDATA[IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS]]></hint></outline_data></other_xml>","",913862273,3187,13329000,"","","(#keys=1) ""CCIJC"".""ADD_BUS_DAYS""(SYSDATE@!,1)[7], ""A"".""STATUS_DATE""[DATE,7]",1,"SEL$117FC0EF"
"",2134,26-APR-23,"","NESTED LOOPS","","","","","",,"","",,2,1,2,1,676,828767,6630136,"","","",,"","","",128144472,645,,"","","(#keys=0) ""A"".""STATUS_DATE""[DATE,7]",1,""
"",2134,26-APR-23,"","FAST DUAL","","","","","""DUAL""@""SEL$2""",,"","",,3,2,3,1,2,1,,"","","",,"","","",7271,2,,"","","",1,"SEL$117FC0EF"
"",2134,26-APR-23,"","INDEX","FAST FULL SCAN","","CCIJC","EPISODES_IDX_006","""A""@""SEL$1""",,"INDEX","ANALYZED",,4,2,3,2,674,828767,6630136,"","","",,"","","",128137200,643,,"","","""A"".""STATUS_DATE""[DATE,7]",1,"SEL$117FC0EF"
```

Comment: look at putting the function in a WITH clause

Comment: I tried that; no effect. I'm thinking there should be some way to fool it into recognizing it's a totally static subquery.

Comment: read this - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-function-calls-from-sql#deterministic-hint and try to add the DETERMINISTIC hint to the function

Comment: As per the linked duplicates you need to force Oracle to materialize the sub-query rather than pushing the function call to the outer query and running it on every row. You can either: 1) use the `NO_MERGE` hint; 2) add a `WHERE ROWNUM > 0` filter to the subquery; or 3) use the (undocumented) `materialize` hint.

Comment: Thanks! @MT0, interestingly, only "materialize" worked of those three suggestions, and only when I called the CTE from a left join rather than a cross join. I still need to test deterministic, it's just a hassle for me to alter functions.

Comment: @BernieL `DETERMINISTIC` will probably not stop the function from being called multiple times; however, it may be able to cache the function result so it may appear faster as it only partially evaluates the function each iteration (i.e. the function is called N times for N rows but only fully evaluated on the first pass and the 2nd pass onwards can use the cached value and only has to be evaluated up to the point of checking the cache). Materializing the sub-query should result in the function only being called once.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EuYcbpA9) (takes a while to run as I deliberately slowed the function call down) shows `ROWNUM > 0` and the `NO_MERGE` hint working with `CROSS JOIN` as their queries are much faster. (However, in the opposite result to you, `materialize` did not work).